# Select Item in ListView on clicking a button inside a ListView item using MVVM

Tags: c#, listview, button, mvvm, uwp

I have a ListView, where each ListView item contains a Button. On clicking on the button, the respective ListView Item should be selected. When the button is clicked I want to execute a command in my ViewModel from the button and pass the SelectedItem from the ListView as a CommandParameter. All of this without having to press the ListView item itself.

How do I solve this using the MVVM pattern?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14056939/wpf-button-in-listview-can-not-see-command-in-viewmodel

Comment: It is not a duplicate of the link you just sent, unfortunately :/

Comment: How so? It is about Button inside ListViewItem binded with proper CommandParameter. I suppose the same is about your question, is it not?

Comment: I'm sorry! It is almost a duplicate. It works the using x:bind as commandparameter instead of Binding.

Comment: Happy to help; )